# How to play a video in mxf format on the web?

Tags: c#, web, browser, media-player, mxf

**Hello . Good time**
I am looking for a **player** for **browsers** (chrome, firefox, edge) that can** play .mxf files** in the internal network and can **get different positions** with it and can jump to different parts of the videos. Or at least a way to do this with a special extension.
**Note:** I do not intend to change the format for the player

For example, can Video.js or Flowplayer or JW Player or VLC Web Plugin play mxf format?

Answer (score 0):

No one answered me. A not so good way that I found is to use a media server and stream movies to the web.
And it seems that this is the only way.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).